# I'm having a difficulty in getting score from the following site

Tags: python, web-scraping

https://rarity.tools/alphabetty-doodles/view/1644
I'm having a difficulty in__ scraping__ all the green colored values from the above mentioned site.. Can you guys help me to get this done without selenium? [image]

Comment: What have you tried? What is being returned? Can you share any of the code you are using?

Comment: Look at the json files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://projects.rarity.tools/static/config/alphabetty-doodles.json  || https://projects.rarity.tools/static/staticdata/alphabetty-doodles.json || https://data.rarity.tools/prices/alphabetty-doodles. Looks like they contain what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much..

Comment: I am glad I managed to help.